# Service Not accessible using Container Host Name from within the Container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apache-kafka, docker-compose

We have been facing an issue while trying to spin up a local containerized confluent kafka ecosystem using docker-compose tool.

**Host OS (Virtual Machine connecting through RDP)**

```
$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ uname -a
Linux IS*******1 4.15.0-189-generic #200-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 19:53:37 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ghosh.sayak@ISRXDLKFD001:~$
```

**Docker Engine**

```
$ sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.20
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        9fdeb9c
 Built:             Tue Oct 18 18:20:19 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.20
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       03df974
  Built:            Tue Oct 18 18:18:11 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.16
  GitCommit:        31aa4358a36870b21a992d3ad2bef29e1d693bec
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

**docker-compose.yaml (Compose created network "kafka_default" using default bridge driver)**

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
   

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.3.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.6.0-7.3.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:      
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter    
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "false"     
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.2.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java/ConnectPlugin"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
      CONNECT_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE: 'false'
    volumes:
       - ./connect-plugins:/usr/share/java/ConnectPlugin        
       
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.3.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
```

Now, while executing the command `$ sudo docker-compose up -d`, we could  only observed that the "zookeeper" container is only getting Up and the "broker" i.e. Kafka container is Exited with Status 1 with the following error -

```
$ sudo docker container logs -t --details broker
2023-02-08T14:07:30.660123686Z  ===> User
2023-02-08T14:07:30.662518281Z  uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
2023-02-08T14:07:30.666677333Z  ===> Configuring ...
2023-02-08T14:07:34.144645597Z  ===> Running preflight checks ... 
2023-02-08T14:07:34.147953062Z  ===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
2023-02-08T14:07:34.564183498Z  ===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ...
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861623527Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,856] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.3--6401e4ad2087061bc6b9f80dec2d69f2e3c8660a, built on 04/08/2021 16:35 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861652177Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:host.name=broker (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861683838Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:java.version=11.0.16.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861689083Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861694000Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu11-ca (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861703288Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/disk-usage-agent-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/paranamer-2.8.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-annotations-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/re2j-1.6.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/snakeyaml-1.30.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/utility-belt-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.6.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-metadata-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-storage-api-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/common-utils-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/logredactor-1.0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-raft-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-server-common-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-logging_2.13-3.9.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jose4j-0.7.9.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-reflect-2.13.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-library-2.13.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-java8-compat_2.13-1.0.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-core-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/minimal-json-0.9.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-clients-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-storage-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jolokia-jvm-1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka_2.13-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-databind-2.13.2.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/logredactor-metrics-1.0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/gson-2.9.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/reload4j-1.2.19.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/metrics-core-4.1.12.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/commons-cli-1.4.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861725300Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861730555Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861734946Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861740934Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861745386Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861749485Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:os.version=4.15.0-189-generic (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.861754326Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:user.name=appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.862778083Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.862781895Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.862785144Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=242MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.862788600Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=4006MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.862792192Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,857] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=252MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.875374527Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,869] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper:2181 sessionTimeout=40000 watcher=io.confluent.admin.utils.ZookeeperConnectionWatcher@3c0a50da (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.875395839Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,873] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.898794157Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,894] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 1048575 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
2023-02-08T14:07:35.910713716Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:35,905] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.094475506Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:36,087] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.19.0.2:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.094498351Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:36,090] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.114680668Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:36,111] ERROR Unable to open socket to zookeeper/172.19.0.2:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121566533Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:36,112] WARN Session 0x0 for sever zookeeper/172.19.0.2:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121606559Z  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121610572Z      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121614024Z      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:483)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121617448Z      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:472)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121620610Z      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121623850Z      at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.registerAndConnect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:260)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121627034Z      at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:270)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121630306Z      at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1177)
2023-02-08T14:07:36.121633562Z      at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1210)
2023-02-08T14:07:37.230453807Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:37,224] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.19.0.2:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-02-08T14:07:37.230488726Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:37,224] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2023-02-08T14:07:37.230492954Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:37,224] ERROR Unable to open socket to zookeeper/172.19.0.2:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO)
2023-02-08T14:07:37.230496368Z  [2023-02-08 14:07:37,225] WARN Session 0x0 for sever zookeeper/172.19.0.2:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

To debug the connectivity, I have done couple of flight checks like -

1. Created a netshoot container within same "kafka_default" network using `sudo docker run -it --net container:zookeeper nicolaka/netshoot`
2. Some useful information -

```
zookeeper# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.19.0.2  zookeeper
```

```
zookeeper# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search corp.***.com
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

2. Tried nslookup, netcat, ping, nmap, telnet from within the container and the results are following -

```
zookeeper# nslookup zookeeper 
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   zookeeper
Address: 172.19.0.2
```

```
zookeeper# nc -v -l -p 2181
nc: Address in use
```

```
zookeeper# ping -c 2 zookeeper
PING zookeeper (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from zookeeper (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from zookeeper (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms

--- zookeeper ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1015ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.049/0.051/0.054/0.002 ms
```

```
zookeeper# nmap -p0- -v -A -T4 zookeeper      
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-02-08 15:43 UTC
NSE: Loaded 155 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 15:43
Scanning zookeeper (172.19.0.2) [65536 ports]
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 15:43, 2.96s elapsed (65536 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 15:43
Initiating OS detection (try #1) against zookeeper (172.19.0.2)
Retrying OS detection (try #2) against zookeeper (172.19.0.2)
NSE: Script scanning 172.19.0.2.
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.01s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.00s elapsed
Nmap scan report for zookeeper (172.19.0.2)
Host is up (0.000060s latency).
Not shown: 65533 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT      STATE    SERVICE    VERSION
2181/tcp  filtered eforward
8080/tcp  filtered http-proxy
39671/tcp filtered unknown
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
Network Distance: 0 hops

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 15:43
Completed NSE at 15:43, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.55 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 65551 (2.885MB) | Rcvd: 131094 (5.508MB)
```

```
zookeeper# telnet localhost 2181
Connected to localhost
```

```
***zookeeper# telnet zookeeper 2181
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.19.0.2): Connection refused***
```

**BUT, WHEN, tried from Host Machine**, it succeeded -

```
ghosh.sayak@IS********1:~/Kafka$ telnet localhost 2181
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

Also, here is the current status of the container -

```
ghosh.sayak@IS********1:~/Kafka$ sudo docker-compose ps
[sudo] password for ghosh.sayak: 
     Name                  Command            State                               Ports                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
broker            /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 1                                                               
connect           /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 1                                                               
control-center    /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 1                                                               
schema-registry   /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 1                                                               
zookeeper         /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up       0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp,:::2181->2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

**NOTE**: Docker Engine has been freshly installed by following this [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

Stuck with this issue! Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using an ARM CPU on your Ubuntu host, you should be using 7.3.1 image tags. Or just upgrade to that tag anyway to get latest changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OneCricketeer for your suggestion. Firstly I am going to check what is CPU type of the machine. And as per your advice, will upgrade the docker tags and let you know here in the comments.

Comment: @OneCricketeer first of all, the host machine is having AMD CPU. And as per your suggestion, I tried to deploy with 7.3.1 as well as 'latest' image tag. Initially thought the issue has been fixed as I am able to up the containers but again the same issue started coming while I executed ```$ sudo docker-compose down``` ```$ sudo docker-compose up -d``` . Isn't it strange? Any suggestion in this regard please?

Comment: Yeah, not really sure. You could try APT instead - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html

Comment: Thanks for your help @OneCricketeer . As you mentioned, I will try to use APT instead.

Comment: Hi @sayak_ghosh90, have you been able to fix this? I'm facing a similar problem

Comment: Hi @PVM I tried but unfortunately, didn't find any conclusion as the same docker ecosystem is working as expected on my other Ubuntu box. This problem may be occurred due to the version of the Ubuntu. Not Sure!